# query formation

Tags: mysql, sql, mybatis

I wanted to write a query to delete from x table and y table where object id="123" selecting object id from z table for the given name in 'z' table.How to write a sql query for this ?

Please let me know .

Comment: Have you tried something yet ?

Comment: i was not able to form this query.

Comment: To the close voter: I agree that the question is light on details, but it certainly won't `solicit debates, arguments, polling or extended discussion`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't delete from two tables at once.  You need two delete statements.

```
DELETE
  x
WHERE
  object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM z WHERE name = 'whatever')

DELETE
  y
WHERE
  object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM z WHERE name = 'whatever')
```

I've used `IN` just in case you have multiple objects with the same name.  You may want to change that behaviour to suit your needs.

Comment: I want to delete from both the tables X and Y at a time

Comment: @harqs - `You can't delete from two tables at once.` That's a solid fact. You can use transactions around the code above to make it `appear` that way, but it simply *can't* be done as a single statement.

Comment: I perform like this for select ,but not aware how to change this for delete  <select id="a" parameterType="map"
  statementType="CALLABLE" resultMap="MAP">
  select objProp.actual_object_id,
  objProp.is_shared
  from t_object objProp
  where objProp.actual_object_id =
  #{domainObject.id}
 </select>

Answer (score 3):

Try This..

```
delete t1,t2 from x t1 inner join y t2 on t1.id=t2.id where t1.id in 
(SELECT object_id FROM z WHERE name = 'YourName');
```

Tested on `Mysql`.

Comment: can u please explain this query

Comment: Here `t1` and `t2` are alias of your table `x` and `y`. This query is selecting `object_id` from `z` table as per your desired name and deleting respected rows with help of their alias (`t1 and t2`) from table `x and y`.

Comment: how can i use this query in the form of mybatis delete syntax?

Comment: Sorry Harqs, as you tagged the question under `mysql, sql` tags, i gave you mysql tested syntax. I have no idea about `mybatis`.

Comment: actually mybatis has the same syntax just we have to embed like <delete id="delete" parameterClass="int">
   DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE
   WHERE  id = #id#
</delete>

Comment: i want to delete from x_table and y_table where id=select id from z_table where obj_id="1234" also at the same time i want to delete 
from user_table id = select id from z_table where obj_id="1234" and user_id != in (select user id from main_table)

Comment: `delete t1,t2,u from x t1 inner join y t2 on t1.id=t2.id left join user u on t1.id=u.id and u.id not in (select user_id from main_table) where t1.id in 
(SELECT object_id FROM z WHERE name = 'YourName');`

Again this is mysql syntax.. do convert in `mybatis`.

Comment: Is giving me error in syntax-----delete t_client1,t_group1 from t_client_permission t_client1 inner join t_group_permission t_group1 on t_client1.object_id=t_group1.object_id where t_client1.object_id in 
  (SELECT obj.object_id FROM t_object obj WHERE obj.actual_object_id = '1510');

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: there? can u please check what is wrong in query

Answer (score 0):

Delete from different tables in a single batch (pool) is a synchronus process, ie it executes one by one, so you need to write 2 different queries to delete any data according to your requirement.

Assuming there is only 1 data for the given name
DELETE X
WHERE object_id = object_id FROM Z WHERE name = 'name'
DELETE y
WHERE object_id = object_id FROM z WHERE name ='name'

this gives better performance then 'IN'

Well offcourse if you have multiple records for a single name then you have to use 'IN'